# How many points to I need before being able to offer a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I don't see a bounty button on a question of mine that's older than 48 hours and when I checked the [bounty FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), all it says is:

```
If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the following applies:

    * The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.
    * You already have an outstanding bounty. You can only have one open bounty at any one time. To start a bounty on this question, you must award the previous bounty first.
    * The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.
```

Since none of the 3 points above apply to my question, I am wondering: Are there additional requirements for a bounty button to show up?

Comment: Guess you have enough points to do that!

Comment: The page you linked to has the required reputation in very large text on the right side of the page. :)

Comment: @Chris You're right. Sometimes I could be so blind. :-/

Comment: The OP has a point though.  It should say _If you have the privilege to set bounties and you don't see the bounty button..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [75 points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to start a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

If you look on the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), you need 75 reputation points and must also wait for 48 hours before adding a bounty.

[Here's the bounty explanation page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum rep of 75 required, as mentioned on the top right of the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) for setting bounties.